# How to force GZIP to read file when CRC check fails

Tags: python-3.x, csv, gzip, zlib, crc32

I'm reading a bunch of gzip compressed files in Python using the gzip module. Unfortunately some of them fail the CRC check, so I'm looking for ways to go around this problem. Looking around StackOverflow I found some very old (2009) answers to this, and without code examples, so it looks like it's possible to basically ignore the CRC check using the underlying zlib library, but I can't figure out how to do it practically.
This is a simple version of my code:

```
def check():
    filenames = ['myfile_1.csv.gz', 'myfile_2.csv.gz']
    for name in filenames:
        data = gzip.open(name, 'r')
        for row in data.read().splitlines():
            # do stuff
            pass
        data.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `data.read()` use `data.read(1)` to read one byte at a time. This will make sure you can squeeze out the very last byte before the error. Use `'rb'` to read binary. Do it in a `try` to catch the error.

```
import sys
import gzip
with gzip.open('bad.gz', 'rb') as gz:
    try:
        while True:
            got = gz.read(1)
            if len(got) == 0:
                break
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(got)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I ended up modifying gzip lib to print the error instead of raising it, and only 1 line was corrupted

Comment: If only the CRC is corrupted, then you can extract all of the data.